# Accessing the query variable from within callback

Tags: javascript, properties, closures

Take the following example:

```
getOptions() {

  let options = {};

  if (this.props.location.hasOwnProperty('query')) {

    const query = this.props.location.query;

    const queriesMap = {
      'createdBy': 'createdBy',
      'state': 'state',
      'created_from': 'created_at[from]',
      'created_to': 'created_at[to]'
    };

    Object.keys(query).map(function(key) {

      if(queriesMap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        options = Object.assign(options, { queriesMap[key]: query[key] });
      }
    });
  }

  return options;
}
```

I'm using the `queriesMap` object to map url parameters to build a new url to call an API. The problem is that `query` is undefined when I'm trying to access it from within the .map callback.

How do I access the `query` variable?

Comment: query is accessible. But you are missing brackets around queriesMap[key]

Comment: don't use `Object.assign()` for that. `options[ queriesMap[key] ] = query[key];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a `[]` around `queriesMap[key]`. So it should be `options = Object.assign(options, { [queriesMap[key]]: query[key] });`.

Also, you could just do `options[queriesMap[key]] = query[key]` rather than `Object.assign`

Comment: You're right. It works with brackets around queriesMap, but it is not at all obvious to me why this is needed? If I stop the debugger on that line and try to print out `[queriesMap[key]]` it gives me the string value wrapped in an array. I would assume I should have the string value directly to build an object like that?

Comment: Check out the "Computed property names" section under https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

Comment: Basically, to use a computed property name in an object literal you have to follow the bracket syntax. I'm not sure why you debugger was behaving that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes sense. Another thing that sent me off track was that when I tried passing an object like { 'test': 'test' } into `Object.assign` my debugger literally told me that `query` was undefined when I tried printing it to the console. When I changed that line back and added the brackets I could access it just fine. Some funky things going on, but I have a nice working solution now.